# Questions about Firebase and MySQL in a mobile app

Tags: mysql, firebase, ionic-framework

I'm fairly new to programming and I'm studying App development with Ionic and using Laravel as a backend. So far I have created a simple system with sign up and login of users and creation of "events" by the users. I have made the relation between the users and events as the app will need to know which user created an event, and the participants of such event.

Now, I was wondering about adding a messaging system between users and obviously push notifications and stuff and came across Firebase. I've read about it before, but haven't really used it so I'm not quite familiar with it.

My question is, is it possible or even recommended that I use both MySQL and Firebase in my app or should I just stick to one? I've read about Websockets if I stick with Laravel, but on the other hand, Firebase also handles user login and registration in case I want to move to Firebase completely. I'm having some technical questions, such as:

- if I'm using both MySQL and Firebase in my app, how would I connect the user that was registered with an ID and a username stored in my MySQL to Firebase, which will need to know which user has sent a message to another one? Can that be done, or recommended?
- Should I just stick with just one for my use case (MySQL or Firebase, instead of both)?

I have researched about use cases similar to mine and couldn't find anything, if you guys have come across such situation, could you recommend any materials? It would be much appreciated!

Thanks a lot everyone! I hope my questions were clear, if you need more details, please let me know!

Comment: For broad questions like this that are also seeking an opinion, I suggest instead posting to a discussion forum such as Reddit.  https://www.reddit.com/r/Firebase/

Comment: Hi Doug, thanks for the suggestion, will do that for sure! Here I was actually looking for technical tips really, examples of similar use cases with technical solutions/suggestions (how do I connect Firebase to MySQL in such use case).

Comment: While this is a pretty good question, it's not well suited for this site. SO is more for specific programming questions that can be answered with a solution. There's really no solution to your question. For example, asking *should I just stick to one* is asking for our opinion to which we would have to have a full understanding of your use case; and it's not a technical question. Another example; you have multiple requirements; data storage, authentication, notifications. Does your data need to be live updating? If yes, Firebase is well suited for that. If no then...? It's really too broad.

Comment: I see @Jay, makes sense, sometimes due to my inexperience, I think there are, well, not technical answers, but something like: "if you're doing simple authentication, notifications, push, etc, then Firebase makes much more sense than MySQL due to its high maintenance, for instance, what if x or y happen? or z?". You know? I think it could not be just opinion, but someone more experienced that tells me that mixing both might probably not be the best solution due to x y z reasons (that I might not see yet)! I totally get your answer though, thanks Jay!

Answer (score 1):

If you decide to use Firebase, it comes with a built-in authentication system so you wouldn't need a MySQL database or your own server.

If you decide to use both anyways (if you have a good reason to do so), you would have to handle all the logic for copying the authenticated user id over to firebase (and validating access) on your own server. If you don't need to do that just keep it simple: Firebase or your own server + MySQL.

Comment: Hi rs7, thanks for the answer, yes I share the same opinion. I was really looking for some technical positions, such as, when you say "if you have a good reason to do so", what reasons would those be? Let's say, I don't have a team to maintain an app that can become quite complicated if I build my own API, however, the app is not also a huge one, so it might be possible. Is it? Or am I being too simplistic? So in a similar use case, would it be "smart" to keep it simple as you said or could I mix both Firebase and MySQL and take advantage of them 2? Thanks rs7!

Comment: Hi @DisplayName, I honestly cannot think of a good reason to do so. Deciding whether you want to go with your own server vs Firebase really depends on what you are trying to build. If you need real time sync for example, better go with Firebase since all the logic is already built in. Whereas if you have to code that logic yourself it might a bit too complex and time consuming.

Comment: Yep, makes sense, thanks a lot for your answer rs7! I believe at the moment I'll probably stick with Firebase only rather than building my own API and maintain it. I'm thinking more of getting a solution first, than later make bigger changes if necessary. Thanks again!

Comment: Glad I was able to help out.Good luck.